# If $\tan^{-1}x + \tan^{-1}y=a+b\tan^{-1}(\frac{x+y}{1-xy})$ then what would be the sum of all possible values of $a$ and $b$?

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan^{-1}x + \tan^{-1}y=a+b\tan^{-1}(\frac{x+y}{1-xy})$ then what would be the sum of all possible values of $a$ and $b$? Please explain how to solve this and these type of problems.

Comment: Do you mean that the equality is true for all $x,y$ (such that the expression is defined)?

Comment: I guess yes and its not an inequality btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

let
$$
\tan^{-1}x=\alpha \qquad \tan^{-1}y=\beta
$$

so that:
$$
x=\tan \alpha \qquad y=\tan \beta \qquad \frac{x+y}{1-xy}= \tan(\alpha + \beta)
$$

your equation becomes:
$$
\alpha+\beta=a+b(\alpha+\beta)
$$

If it is true for (almost) all $\alpha, \beta$, can you find $a, b$? (Why the almost?)

Comment: Uhmm yes but really where is it not true. I'm unable to judge it

Comment: should a be equal to 0 and b be equal to 1?

Comment: Yes, correct. And $\alpha, \beta$ must be such that $\frac{x+y}{1-xy}$ is defined.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help. I guess the problem is solved then.